# Defining variable in function after return

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm stemming some words in a Pandas dataframe and have the following function:

```
progress = 0

def stem(x):
    end = time.time()
    tokens = word_tokenize(x)
    global progress
    progress += 1
    sys.stdout.write('\r {} percent, {} position, {} per second '.format(float(progress / len(articles)), 
                                                             progress, progress / (end - start)))

    return [stemmer.stem(e) for e in tokens]
```

The way I'm calling that function is like this:

```
start = time.time()
articles['stems'] = articles.content.apply(lambda x: stem(x))
```

in which `articles.content` is a column of large strings. The last variable in `sys.stdout.write`, as currently written, calculates the average number of rows iterated over per second. What I'd like to do is calculate the instantaneous rate for each row. The challenge is that `start` would have to be defined after I return the stemmed words.

I tried defining a new variable inside the lambda expression and then learned that that's not possible. And I know that `return [stemmer.stem...], start = time.time()` would include `start` in the values of the dataframe, which obviously I don't want.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I can assign the stemmed words to a variable, redefine `start` and return the variable with the stemmed words:

progress = 0
start = time.time()

```
def stem(x):
    end = time.time()
    tokens = word_tokenize(x)
    global start
    global progress
    progress += 1
    stems = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in tokens]
    end = time.time()
    sys.stdout.write('\r {} percent, {} position, {} per second '.format(str(float(progress / len(articles))), 
                                                         str(progress), (1 / (end - start))))   
    start = time.time()
    return stems

start = time.time()
stem(strings)
```